# Map Array not getting Updated via setState- React Function

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, react-hooks, setstate

I'm trying to add an expense item to the array list via setState.
The array is getting added but is not coming up in the UI via map function-

```
const saveExpense=(expense)=>{
    console.log(expense)
    setexpenseItems((previousState)=>{
      return[expense,...previousState]
    })
  
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <NewExpense onSave={saveExpense}/>
        {console.log(expenseItems)}
        {expenseItems.map(item=>{
          return(
            <ExpenseItems key={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            amount={item.amount}
            date={item.date}></ExpenseItems>
          )
        
        })}
       
      </header>
    </div>
  );
```

--Expense Item Component--

```
function ExpenseItems(props){
    const [title,setTitle]=useState(props.title)

    const ClickHandler=()=>{
      setTitle('Updated Title')  
      console.log(title)
     
    }
    const onFilterValue=(filterValueArg)=>{
      let filterValue=filterValueArg
      console.log(filterValue)
     } 
     console.log("Displaying the content of the array")
     console.log(props)
    return(
      <div>
      <ExpensesFilter onFilterValue={onFilterValue}/>
       <Card>
           <div className='expense-item'>
           <ExpenseDate date={props.date}></ExpenseDate>
           <div className='expense-item__description'><h2>{title}</h2></div>
           <div>{props.date?.toISOString()}</div>
           <div className='expense-item__price'>${props.amount}</div>
           <button onClick={ClickHandler}>Click Here!</button>
           </div>
       </Card>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Ignore the ClickHandler since it is used for some other purpose.

Comment: can you also add code for `ExpenseItems` component ?

Comment: Updated, try checking now!

Comment: move code from return[expense,...previousState] this to this return[...previousState,expense]

Comment: Have tried it, still the same.
Content is still not getting displayed during map array.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the example of a todo list [**Link**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-todo-list-p912n?file=/src/TodoList.js)

**TodoList.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"; 
function TodoList() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { id: uuid(), task: "task 1" },
    { id: uuid(), task: "task 2" }
  ]);

  const create = newTodo => {
    console.log(newTodo);
    setTodos([...todos, newTodo]);
  };

  const todosList = todos.map(todo => (
    <Todo
      key={todo.id}
      todo={todo}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="TodoList">
      <h1>
        Todo List <span>A simple React Todo List App</span>
      </h1>
      <ul>{todosList}</ul>
      <NewTodoForm createTodo={create} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**NewTodoForm.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from "react"; 

function NewTodoForm({ task, createTodo }) {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
    {
      task: ""
    }
  ); 

  const handleSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const newTodo = { id: uuid(), task: userInput.task};
    createTodo(newTodo);
    setUserInput({ task: "" });
  };

  return (
    <form className="NewTodoForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="task">New todo</label>
      <input
        value={userInput.task} 
        id="task"
        type="text"
        name="task"
        placeholder="New Todo"
      />
      <button>Add Todo</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```